# Copying files from one machine to another in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, iis

I'm currently generating documentation on one machine, and publishing it to a web server using the following commands in a script:

```
net use "\\someShare" PASSWORD /user:username
del /S /Q "\\someShare"
xcopy /E /Y Documentation\html\* "\\someShare\"
```

However, it feels like a really bad idea to have a password as plain text in the script, so I'm looking for alternatives to my current solution. Ideas?

I definitely would appreciate a solution that uses some kind of access control, as many different people should be allowed to publish their own documentation to the web server, but not mess with each other's docs.

Answer (score 0):

if your script runs interactively you can ask the credential to use, and use the New-PSDrive cmdlet :

```
$cred=get-credential
New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\server\share -Credential $cred  # you may add -Persist to have a peristent drive
```

if you want the script to run whithout interaction you have to save your credential to a file for example :

```
$Cred.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Set-Content $env:USERPROFILE\$env:USERNAME.txt
```

when you need the pass :

```
$Pass = Get-Content $env:USERPROFILE\$env:USERNAME.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("username@domain.com",$Password)
```

Comment: It's not an interactive script. The second solution seems pretty sweet. I'll try it out!

Comment: beaware that it's a per-user mechanism, one user cant use the credentials saved by another